# Works Cited page on website with everything except first line indented

Tags: html, css

I have a responsive site that has a bibliography. I want the text to show up like a works cited page, no matter what the width of the browser is.

So the publications on this page: http://www.lajsa.org/news-announcements/new-publications/

Should have all the lines under the first line indented 30px. Like the image here: http://libguides.mjc.edu/MLA/mlaworkscited

I thought I could do this:

```
p { padding-left:30px;}
p::first-line { padding-left: -30px !important;}
```

or this:

```
p:not(::first-line) { padding-left:30px;}
```

But it didn't work.

Here is some sample HTML:

```
<p>Aizenberg, Edna. <em>On the Edge of the Holocaust: The Shoah in Latin American Literature and Culture</em>. Waltham: Brandeis UP/UP of New England, 2016. 200 pp. 19 illustrations. ISBN: 978-1-61168-856-6.</p>
<p>Aizenberg, Edna. <em>Parricide on the Pampa? A New Study and Translation of Alberto Gerchunoff´s </em>Los gauchos judíos. 2nd edition. Madrid /Frankfurt: Iberoamericana /Vervuert, 2015. 166 pp. ISBN: 9788484898849. Contains updated introduction and bibliography.</p>
<p>Balbuena, Monique Rodrigues. <em>Homeless Tongues: Poetry and Languages of the Sephardic Diaspora</em>. Stanford: Stanford UP, 2016.</p>
<p>Blajberg, Israel. <em>Star of David in the Southern Cross: Memory of Jewish presence&nbsp;in the armed forces of Brazil – from Cabral to Haiti</em>. Resende, RJ: – AHIMTB,&nbsp;Brazilian Military History Academy, 2015. 680 pp. 330 Illustrations. ISBN: 978-85-60811-24-3.</p>
```

I can't just add a span in the middle as suggested here: [Indenting the 2nd line of a paragraph with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17158253/indenting-the-2nd-line-of-a-paragraph-with-css) because the line break will change depending on screen width.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
p {
  padding-left: 30px;
  text-indent: -30px;
}
```

```html
<p>Aizenberg, Edna. <em>On the Edge of the Holocaust: The Shoah in Latin American Literature and Culture</em>. Waltham: Brandeis UP/UP of New England, 2016. 200 pp. 19 illustrations. ISBN: 978-1-61168-856-6.</p>
<p>Aizenberg, Edna. <em>Parricide on the Pampa? A New Study and Translation of Alberto Gerchunoff´s </em>Los gauchos judíos. 2nd edition. Madrid /Frankfurt: Iberoamericana /Vervuert, 2015. 166 pp. ISBN: 9788484898849. Contains updated introduction and bibliography.</p>
<p>Balbuena, Monique Rodrigues. <em>Homeless Tongues: Poetry and Languages of the Sephardic Diaspora</em>. Stanford: Stanford UP, 2016.</p>
<p>Blajberg, Israel. <em>Star of David in the Southern Cross: Memory of Jewish presence&nbsp;in the armed forces of Brazil – from Cabral to Haiti</em>. Resende, RJ: – AHIMTB,&nbsp;Brazilian Military History Academy, 2015. 680 pp. 330 Illustrations. ISBN: 978-85-60811-24-3.</p>
```

Comment: You rock! Thank you!

Comment: @MattM, since this worked for you you may consider checking it as the correct answer