# How to indent the first line if and only if there are 2 or more lines to display?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I have a `div` tag that displays plain text. Depending on the width of the text or the div, the text may be displayed on one line or multiple lines.

Task:

How to indent the first line only when there are 2 or more lines?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Indent starting from the second line of a paragraph with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17158253/indent-starting-from-the-second-line-of-a-paragraph-with-css)

Comment: nope, not the same question

Comment: you need some JS code for that

Answer (score 0):

The text-indent property specifies the indentation of the first line in a text-block.

```
div p {
  text-indent: 2em;
}
```

If you want to apply this to the first paragraph only in the div you can use  **:first-child** Selector

```
div p:first-child {
  text-indent: 2em;
}
```